# In format.default(nam.ob, width = max(ncn), justify = "left") : NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

Tags: r, disk.frame

I have a disk frame that I've saved into a file. It's made up of ten chunks.

I coded every one of the columns as a character because I intend on combining these individual disk frames into one large disk frame and setting the column types at that point.

I wanted to pull the disk frame from it's file with this code

```
my_disk.frame <- 
  disk.frame("folder/mydiskframe.df")
```

Unfortunately, it returned this warning message

> Warning messages: 1: In max(ncn) : no non-missing arguments to max;
> returning -Inf 2: In format.default(nam.ob, width = max(ncn), justify
> = "left") :   NAs introduced by coercion to integer range

And when I execute `my_disk.frame`, it shows me this:

```
path: "folder/mydiskframe.df"
nchunks: 0
nrow (at source): 0
ncol (at source): 0
nrow (post operations): ???
ncol (post operations): ???
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case someone gets the same error, it means that you have the wrong pathname.